# problem with polymorphic class

Tags: c++, c++11

This code compiles fine:

```
 int main() 
 { 
   class lm { 
      public: 
       int operator()(int x,int y){ 
          return x+y; 
        }
   }; 

   int x = lm()(10,15);
   return 0;
 }
```

But this doesn't

```
 int main() 
 { 
   template<class T>
   class lm { 
      public:
       T operator()(T x,T y){ 
          return x+y; 
        }
   }; 

   int x = lm()(10,15);
   return 0;
 }
```

Why am I doing this?
because I want to fake a polymorphic lambda function inside of another function.
Other suggestions are also welcome.

Ultimately what i would like to do is:

```
class A{
int m_var;
public:
int f(int x,int y);
}
int A::f(int x, int y)
{
   template<class T>
   class lm { 
      public:
       T operator()(T x,T y){ 
          return x+y+ m_var; //accessing the member variable of class A
        }
   }; 

   int x = lm()(10,15);
   return 0;
}
```

The point is the function object should be able to access the member variable of `class A`
Any workaround will also help.

Answer (score 2):

A local class cannot have member templates (this is the case in both C++03 and C++11).

The obvious solution is to move the class so that it is at namespace scope:

```
namespace {
    struct lm {
        template <typename T> T operator()(T x, T y) { return x + y; }
    };
}

int main() {  
    int x = lm()(10,15); 
}
```

If you want to "associate" the template with the function in which it is meant to be used, stick it in a `main_stuff` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking seems needlessly complex to me. Avoid such code.

- A local class will not automatically 'capture' members of enclosing class `A`.
- The template argument to the local class `lm` is unused and superfluous.
- Also, it won't compile as such because `T` hides `T`.
- usage of `lm()(10,15)` will at least require a template argument to `lm<int>()` according to the class definition (type inference is only supported for function class)
- The *genericity* of the local `lm` class is fake: the enclosing function call guarantees the static types of `x` and `y` to be `int`s.

Sigh. Here's what I'd do:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    const T m_var;

public:
    A(T var) : m_var(var) {}

    T operator()(T x, T y) const
    {
        return x + y + m_var;
    }
};

template <typename T>
A<T> helper(T var)
{
    return A<T>(var);
}

int main()
{
    return helper(42)(10,15);
}
```

returning `67`